# I have a custom dialog....I need to change its orientation to Landscape mode always

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a class that extends Dialog. I'm calling its constructor and passing an arraylist to it. This dialog has a listview and I want to set its orientation to LANDSCAPE mode.

Here is how I am calling the Dialog's constructor:

```
itemsList = itemXMLHandler.getItemsList();

 ManagePartListActivity partListActivity = new ManagePartListActivity(mActivity,itemsList);
 Window window = partListActivity.getWindow();
 WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
 lp.copyFrom(window.getAttributes());
 //This makes the dialog take up the full width
 lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
 lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
 window.setAttributes(lp);
 partListActivity.setTitle("Manage Part");
 partListActivity.show();
```

And here is my class that Extends Dialog

```
public class ManagePartListActivity extends Dialog{

 static ListView listView;
ArrayList<ManagePartResponse> list = new ArrayList<ManagePartResponse>();
Context context;
BaseBarcodeActivity mContext;
private static CustomAdapter adapter;

public ManagePartListActivity(ManagePartActivity context,
        ArrayList<ManagePartResponse> itemsList) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    super(context);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_managepart_list);
    this.list=itemsList;
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

            adapter = new CustomAdapter(getContext(), list);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
//              listView.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(getContext(),list));
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        System.out.println("after notify");
        listView.invalidateViews();
    System.out.println("after invalidate");



    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {

            Log.d("LIST", "listview clicked");

            ManagePartResponse managePartResponse =  list.get(position);

            //old logic
  //                Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), MngePrtListClickActivity.class);
//              
//              intent.putExtra("image", managePartResponse.getImage());
//              intent.putExtra("make", managePartResponse.getMake());
//              intent.putExtra("model",managePartResponse.getModel());
//              intent.putExtra("partName", managePartResponse.getPartName());
//              intent.putExtra("year", managePartResponse.getYear());
//              intent.putExtra("partID", managePartResponse.getStockref());
//              getContext().startActivity(intent);
            String stockref = managePartResponse.getStockref();

            //new logic
             new StockIdSearchManage(getContext(), managePartResponse.getStockref(), "");
  //                 new StockIdManage(getContext(), stockref, "");
 //             Intent intent2 = new Intent(getContext(), ShowStockIdManageActivity.class);



        }
    });

}



public static void finishImg() {
    System.out.println("Finisheddddddd");
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    System.out.println("after notify");
    listView.invalidateViews();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way here - create Activity with Dialog theme instead:

```
<activity android:name=".ManagePartListActivity"
          android:screenOrientation="landscape"
          android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

But its only for Activity.
Don't think that you can set smthng the same for dialog.

You should set this parameter for parent Activity.

or you can set it in Manifest.xml

Comment: Where to write this ?

Comment: in onCreate method of Activity

Comment: i'm calling this from a normal java class